# The phantom vertex

Tags: modeling

I am becoming quite crazy (I am new to Blender: I mean more crazy that you usually are). I wont to make a crown, so I designed a single arm with the torus shaped base sector. I tried to use the array modifier to make all the 16 arms but the results were not as they were supposed to be.
After many attempts I found that the bounding box has a strange shape. Therefore I box selected my shape and it has 10.807 vertex out of 10.808. I thought that inverting the selection I could isolate the spare vertex and delete it, but inverting the selection I have 0 vertex selected.
I also tryed to copy the 10.807 vertex and paste them in a different instance of Blender, but the bounding box is still there...
[image]

[image: Crown sector and its bounding box, same view]

[image: The bounding box and the object superimposed with GIMP]

Comment: Go into edit mode, unhide all geometry (alt-h), select-all (a). You should have all vertices selected now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The problem is not selecting all vertices, but deleting the 10.808th, that, apparently, distorts the bounding box. On a theoretical point of view, it should be selected when I invert the selection, after having selected all the "good" ones, but practically the inversion of the selection of 10.807 returns 0 vertexes selected. Alt-h has no effect.

Comment: Perhaps share your file.. or part of it...https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In the end, I solved it but in a weird way. I played a little with select linked and then invert selection, and... it appeared. I deleted the vertex, then adjusted the bounding box rotating the mesh in edit mode and finally, it worked. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5706" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5706/)

Comment: Dear Robin, I uploaded the file. This if it may be intersting. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you know what solved your problem, you are allowed to answer your own questions so others may be helped as well.